# Proyección Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Buen día tengo la siguiente salida en formato json:

```
{
    "_id": "600ffd3db893e86a265bc0fa",
    "blpInfoBasica": {
      "nomIgnoto": "X",
      "emaIgnoto": "X@gmail.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "60f1e84ea56a3396b0862504",
    "blpInfoBasica": {
      "nomIgnoto": "Y",
      "emaIgnoto": "Y@gmail.com"
    }
  }
```

Habrá una manera que se pueda omitir el objecto `blpInfoBasica` y genere una lista asi como el de la siguiente manera:

```
{
    "_id": "600ffd3db893e86a265bc0fa",
     "nomIgnoto": "X",
     "emaIgnoto": "X@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "_id": "60f1e84ea56a3396b0862504",
      "nomIgnoto": "Y",
      "emaIgnoto": "Y@gmail.com"
  }
```

Cualquier ayuda, será bienvenida.
Gracias a todos.

Comment: Renombrar la propiedades en el código que extrae la información puede ser una buena opción. Quizá también se pueda hacer desde MongoDB, pero no sé como sea en tu caso, se requiere más información de cómo se hace la consulta

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. ¿Cómo obtienes esa salida que mencionas? Es necesario ver cómo haces la consulta a la base de datos para poder ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Benjamin y Mauricio, estoy usando la siguiente instrucción const result =  await db.collection('ignotos').find({}).project({_id:1,"blpInfoBasica.nomIgnoto":1,"blpInfoBasica.emaIgnoto":1}).toArray(); pero lo que no quiero es que me aparezca blpInfoBasica el cual contiene los otros datos. Probe mil manera que conozco con las proyecciones pero no me da el resultado deseado. Gracias y espero me haya explicado. Saludos y gracias freddy por redactar mejor la pregunta.

Comment: El problema es que en tu modelo ignotos tienes un colección o un objecto como propiedad, asi como el nomIgnoto, si no cambias tu modelo te seguira retornando eso.

Comment: Agrega esa información en la pregunta, en los comentarios no se entiende bien de qué se trata. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega lo necesario. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Tan solo necesitas usar `$project` junto con `aggregation`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "nomIgnoto": "$blpInfoBasica.nomIgnoto",
      "emaIgnoto": "$blpInfoBasica.emaIgnoto"
    }
  }
])
```

Ejemplo [aquí](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cxMY9K9IC_6)

Answer (score 0):

## replaceRoot

Para hacer algo similar a desempaquetar sin necesidad de referirte a cada uno de los elementos en un objeto puedes utilizar [ReplaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) de la siguiente forma:

`newRoot: "$blpInfoBasica"`, la cual devuelve:

```
nomIgnoto:"X"
emaIgnoto:"X@gmail.com"
```

##### Incluir "_id" padre

Puedes incluir 'merge' en 'replaceroot', de tal forma que unes el mismo _id del padre. Así:

`newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ { _id: "$_id"}, "$blpInfoBasica" ] }`

Resultado:

```
_id:"600ffd3db893e86a265bc0fa"
nomIgnoto:"X"
emaIgnoto:"X@gmail.com"
```

Stage:

```py
    {
        '$replaceRoot': {
            'newRoot': {
                '$mergeObjects': [
                    {
                        '_id': '$_id'
                    }, '$blpInfoBasica'
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```